# What's the meaning of "national life-interests"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Behind this facade disappears the distinction between the just, *national life-interests* of a people, and the aggressive tendencies of imperialist chauvinism. [Source](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=Opwc6W3-DaEC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=Behind+this+facade+disappears+the+distinction+between+the+just,+national+life-interests+of+a+people,+and+the+aggressive+tendencies+of+imperialist+chauvinism.&source=bl&ots=Vl_9LKlgxI&sig=ACfU3U0L_oYSevCmrXBJlsnheiwZizS69Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsmZPc5YT5AhVE9zgGHR0MBpwQ6AF6BAgDEAI)

Comment: You should include the source of the sentence in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the source](http://www.autodidactproject.org/other/lukacs_intellectuals_1948.html), this section is about the "*fetishization of the nation*".

"*the just, national life-interests of a people*" would then mean the natural needs and wishes of a nation or people as a society. This could be things like security, employment, cultural freedom etc.

This is contrasted with "*the aggressive tendencies of imperialist chauvinism*" which could be expansionism, projected power, cultural domination etc.

Comment: can you give me a synonym for it?

Comment: Syn: basic needs of human survival.